# Getting burn calories from open BLE devices

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing an app in which i have to get the burn calories from BLE devices like Mio-Fuse.

I am able to fetch data from Health kit of Apple Watch but when it comes to BLE wearable with out any API, i am not able to track down the service id or characteristics id.So kindly help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have correct UDID for getting characteristics iD. Only you have characteristics iD then you can search for service.

Comment: Are you sure that the device specification exposes a characteristic for burnt calories?

Comment: Yes, i am able to see it in device itself and Mio Go App with the Mio Fuse device is able to track down burned calories but i am not in my app.

They don't have any specific API.

Answer (score 1):

You need to post your code to get help.
First look for your device - The code is obj c but you should be easily able to change accordingly for swift

```
  if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"0x180A"]] options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES}];
    NSLog(@"Start scanning");
}
```

If it succeed, then look for characteristics like this

```
 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
    NSLog(@"Discovered service1: %@", service.UUID);
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
}
if (_discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {
    // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
    _discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

    // And connect
    NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);
    [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
}
```

Once you connect then you will get characteristics

Comment: Any problem with code. Let me know ?

Comment: everything is working fine. i am able to get battery level, heart rate and Manufacturer name also, but i am not getting Service id and its characteristics for getting burned calories.

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

Please check this link. I am not getting any service id to get active energy or burned energy.

Comment: You need to post your code. But only problem seems UDID for that part characteristics is wrong. For other characteristics you must be adding UDID in same way. If its 100% correct then you need to check if is it readable or you need to do something before you can read or write to that characteristics